# How can I parse operands and operators in my calculator project?

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof

I'm working on a calculator project in my free time to keep up my Java skills during the summer, but I have run into a snag. So far everything is working great and it's basically done; I'm just trying to add some functionality.

I'm trying to figure out how I can set it up so that instead of typing <kbd>5</kbd> then clicking `+`, `-`, `/`, or `*` and then typing the second number, how to let the user type `number1(operator)number2`. I'm mostly just looking to try and figure out how to take everything before the operator or key string and then everything after it and make them both separate strings, then I can parse them and add them into the rest of my code. I simply forgot how to get everything before the `+` and after as separate things! I'm assuming I will use `indexOf()` and substrings.

Comment: respectfully disagree with SLaks. regex is not so good at parsing especially when he wants to allow the user to enter complex equations with nested parenthesis and what not (really should allow for that possibility). Again what you need is a parser. Consider using Java's innate JavaScripting abilities to parse your equation.

Comment: avoid handling parentheses. Without parentheses, a regular expression might be enough; with parentheses it becomes a grammar and you need a compiler. See Matcher class for some info about regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `indexOf` and `substring` (assuming this is a simple calculator that does not allow parenthesis or nesting - if it is more complex then use a parser).

`substring` has two forms that will be useful to you:

```
String substring(int startIndex)
String substring(int startIndex, int endIndex)
```

Remember that `endIndex` is *exclusive*, so it will not include the index specified.

Comment: so how exactly would I go about this, mind giving me an example with say the string 44+22? i.e where to put stuff? Really confused on this today for some reason! gah thanks for the help!

Comment: So, `indexOf("+")` will give you the split point. You can then use `substring(0, splitPoint)` and `substring(splitPoint + 1)` to get the prefix and suffix, respectively. Note that you will need to have some special handling if the split point is at the start or end of the string.

Comment: AH okay, perfect, got it working! thank you a million, if I had 15 rep I would upvote you!

Comment: @Calvin Moss, you could accept this answer I think -- click on the tick box.